# r effect estimate plot as error bars by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to create a plot showing effect estimates for 4 different levels of a categorical variable **X** grouped based on a grouping variable **M1** like this. This example below has 5 levels for each variable but my X has 4 levels

[image]

Suppose this is my test dataset with effect estimates

```
effect_data <- data.frame(
  Level = factor(rep(1:4, each = 12)),  # Assuming 12 sets of analyses
  EffectEstimate = runif(48, min = -2, max = 2),  # Replace with your actual effect estimates
  LowerCI = runif(48, min = -3, max = -1),  # Replace with your actual lower CIs
  UpperCI = runif(48, min = 1, max = 3),  # Replace with your actual upper CIs
  M1  = factor(rep(letters[1:12], times = 4))
)
```

My plot ends up looking like this

```
# Plot the effect estimate as a bar chart
ggplot(effect_data, aes(x = Level, y = EffectEstimate)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7, fill = "blue") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LowerCI, ymax = UpperCI), position = position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.25) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(.~Level)+
  labs(
    title = "Effect Estimates with Confidence Intervals",
    x = "Results from 12 different Models",
    y = "Effect Estimate"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

This is not what I want, I am trying to generate a plot like the one above , any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
effect_data <- data.frame(
  Level = factor(rep(1:4, each = 12)),
  # Assuming 12 sets of analyses
  EffectEstimate = runif(48, min = -2, max = 2),
  # Replace with your actual effect estimates
  LowerCI = runif(48, min = -3, max = -1),
  # Replace with your actual lower CIs
  UpperCI = runif(48, min = 1, max = 3),
  # Replace with your actual upper CIs
  M1  = factor(rep(letters[1:12], times = 4))
)
```

From your description I am not sure what you are looking.
Here are two variants. Maybe one of them is what you desire?

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Variant A
ggplot(effect_data,
       aes(
         x = Level,
         y = EffectEstimate,
         group = M1,
         fill = M1
       )) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LowerCI, ymax = UpperCI),
                position = position_dodge(0.7),
                width = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Effect Estimates with Confidence Intervals",
       x = "Results from 12 different Models",
       y = "Effect Estimate") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge",
           width = 0.7) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# Variant B
ggplot(effect_data,
       aes(
         x = M1,
         y = EffectEstimate,
         group = Level,
         fill = Level
       )) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LowerCI, ymax = UpperCI),
                position = position_dodge(0.7),
                width = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Effect Estimates with Confidence Intervals",
       x = "Results from 12 different Models",
       y = "Effect Estimate") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge",
           width = 0.7) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

These plots are so called dynamite plots. Not always recommended (please see the net of pros and cons):

Here is a version using the `ggpattern` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
#install.packages("ggpattern")
library(ggpattern)


ggplot(effect_data, aes(x = M1, y = EffectEstimate, group = Level)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conditional_ymin, ymax = conditional_ymax), 
                width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), color="grey60") +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.7,
                   aes(pattern = as.factor(Level)),
                   pattern_density = 0.1,
                   pattern_spacing = 0.02,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.5,
                   fill = "white",
                   color = "black") +
  labs(title = "Dynamite Plot for Effect Estimates", y = "Effect Estimate", x = "Group") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c("stripe", "crosshatch", "none", "wave"), name = "Level")
```

[image]

Comment: that looks interesting. Amazing. Thanks.